# В чем различия между define() и const?

Tags: php

В чем различия между define() и const?
Так ошибок нету:

```
$r=45;
if ($r==45) {
     define('FOO', 'BAR');
}
echo FOO;
```

Так вылетает ошибка

```
$r=45;
if ($r==45) {
  const FOO = 'BAR';

}
echo FOO;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

const - объявление констант в классе. 
Используйте define и не парьтесь.

UPD:
Основное отличе между define и const в том, что `const` задает константы во время "компиляции", а define - во время исполнения.

- `const` не может использоваться для создания констант в зависимости от условия(ваш случай).

  ```
  if (...) {
      const FOO = 'BAR';    // ваш случай. Интерпретатор пошлет с такой идеей
  }
  // but
  if (...) {
      define('FOO', 'BAR'); // Все ок
  }
  ```

  Это может понадобится, если вы хотите проверить задана константа или нет:

  ```
  if (!defined('FOO')) {
      define('FOO', 'BAR');
  }
  ```

  - `const` принимает только статические данные (число, строку или иную константу, типа `true`, `false`, `null`, `__FILE__`), тогда как `define()` принимает любое выражение:

  const BIT_5 = 1 << 5;    // неверно
  define('BIT_5', 1 << 5); // верно
- `const` позволяет задать имя только напрямую, в отличие от `define()`, которая позволяет собрать имя константы "на лету":

  ```
  for ($i = 0; $i < 32; ++$i) {
      define('BIT_' . $i, 1 << $i);
  }
  ```
- `const` всегда регистрозависима, `define()` позволяет создавать регистронезависимые константы:

  ```
  define('FOO', 'BAR', true);
  echo FOO; // BAR
  echo foo; // BAR
  ```

define работает медленнее(из-за всего, написанного выше), если речь идет о большом числе констант. 
Это если подробнее почитать на SO

Comment: Отличный ответ.Благодарен